# SCSS showing error while parsing argument

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Here is my `scss` code-

```
$perc:100%;

@mixin childAlign($nb,$al){
    td:nth-child($nb){
        text-align:$al;
    }
}
table,th,td{
        border: 1px solid black;
}   
img {
    max-width: $perc;
    max-height: $perc;
}

@include childAlign(1,center);
@include childAlign(2,left);
@include childAlign(3,left);
@include childAlign(4,center);
```

When I try to compile the code its showing error like

> Error: Invalid CSS after "td:nth-child(": expected An+B expression, was "$nb)"
>           on line 4 of C:\Users\ACTECH\Documents\q6\q6.scss, in `childAlign'
>           from line 16 of C:\Users\ACTECH\Documents\q6\q6.scss

But is there any syntactical error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a variable inside a selector, so it has to be interpolated as follow `#{$varName}`.

```
td:nth-child(#{$nb}) { ... }
```

[About Interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)